# How do I get the XML attributes?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to grab the data for several products, then list the attributes for each product. I'm ending up with the same attributes from Attribute id="259". Can anyone fix my problem?
XML example

```
    <AttributeValue id="258888">
<name>HON</name>
</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue id="276682">
<name>Office Star</name>
</AttributeValue>

<Attribute id="296935">
<name>Stores</name>
<AttributeValues>
<AttributeValue id="18893">
<name>Test</name>
</AttributeValue>
</AttributeValues>
</Attribute>
</RelatedAttributes>

    foreach($xml->RelatedAttributes->Attribute as $attribute){
echo $attribute->name; //main Attribute Name

foreach($xml->RelatedAttributes->Attribute->AttributeValues->AttributeValue as $attribute_values){
echo $attribute_values->name; //subtopic for main Attribute

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
foreach($xml->AttributeValue[0]->attributes() as $key => $value) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

Also give a try

```
$attr = $xml->AttributeValue[0]->attributes();
echo $attr['id'];
```